# What is the source of this Prana Pratishtha Mantra?

Tags: vedas, reference-request, agamas

> मानो जूतिर्जुषतामाज्यस्य बृहस्पतिर्यज्ञमिमं तनोत्वरिष्टं यज्ञ गुम समिमं दधातु।
> विश्वेदेवास इह मदयन्ता मोम्प्रतिष्ठ।।
> अस्यै प्राणाः प्रतिष्ठन्तु अस्यै प्राणाः क्षरन्तु च।
> अस्यै देवत्व मर्चायै माम् हेति च कश्चन।।

> māno jūtirjuṣatāmājyasya bṛhaspatiryajñamimaṃ tanotvariṣṭaṃ yajña guma samimaṃ dadhātu।
> viśvedevāsa iha madayantā mompratiṣṭha।।
> asyai prāṇāḥ pratiṣṭhantu asyai prāṇāḥ kṣarantu ca।
> asyai devatva marcāyai mām heti ca kaścana।।

This is the Prana Pratishtha mantra. It appears to me that it may be a Vedic mantra. Not sure. What is the source of this mantra?

Comment: Prana Prathistha is a tantric concept. I'm not sure if there is any evidence of idol worship in Vedanta. The pranaprathistha of rudrakshas, small stones, temporary idols/images and large idols are specified quite well in agamas. There *could* be vedic mantras added later on for purification rites.

Comment: This seems *preparatory* mantra. Prana prathistha mantras have a lot of nyasas and a lot of beeja akharas *hreem*, *shreem*, etc. There are few vedantic/upanishadic prayer chants to conclude them too.

Comment: @User29449 This is Prana Pratishtha Mantra. Nyas is a separate procedure done before Prana Pratishtha. Anybody who does puja knows it.

Comment: @User29449 Puja itself is an Agamic (or Tantric) process.

Comment: I believe prana goes inside the murti after Nyasa. But I exactly don't know it. I'll have to check for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an amalgamation of mantra(s) as in Nirṇaya or Paddhati granthas, possibly of a Vedic mantra (*māno...mompratiṣṭha*) with a Purāṇic or Āgamic one (*asyai...kaścana*).

The **first half** (*māno...mompratiṣṭha*) of the verse can be traced to [Mādhyandinīya Śukla Yajurveda (2.10~13)](https://www.hinduonline.co/vedicreserve/yajur_veda/shukla_yajur_veda.pdf) (albeit with no 'गुम').

> मनो जूतिर्जुषतामाज्यस्य बृहस्पतिर्यज्ञमिमं तनोत्वरिष्टं यज्ञम् समिमं दधातु।
> विश्वेदेवासऽइह मदयन्ताऽमोम्प्रतिष्ठ।।

> mano jūtirjuṣatāmājyasya bṛhaspatiryajñamimaṃ tanotvariṣṭaṃ yajñam samimaṃ dadhātu।
> viśvedevāsa'iha madayantā'mompratiṣṭha।।

> The butter’s rapid flow delight his spirit! Brihaspati extend this act of worship. May he restore the sacrifice uninjured. Here let all Gods rejoice. OM! Step thou forward. *- [Shukla Yajurveda](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/texts-of-the-white-yajurveda-ebook.html) 2.13*

With some variations, it can also be found in a multitude of other Āraṇyaka(s) and Śrautasūtras. I highly doubt you will find such a mantra in Purāṇa or Āgama, except maybe in Vaikhānasāgama which again are Vedic in essence. While I could trace the verse to [Agastya Saṃhitā](https://archive.org/details/agastya-samhita-sage-agastya-bhavanath-jha/page/250/mode/1up?view=theater), it is in the pariśiṣṭa with [questionable authenticity](https://archive.org/details/agastya-samhita-sage-agastya-bhavanath-jha/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater). Similar to this is the occurrence in [Lakṣmīnārāyaṇa Saṃhitā](https://archive.org/details/lakShmInArAyaNasaMhitA2/page/n453/mode/1up?view=theater) which is again of [uncertain origins](https://groups.google.com/g/bvparishat/c/CpjPqzQBTPc).

The **second half** (*asyai...kaścana*) is a fairly common verse in Upāsanā and Arcana-chara. You can find the verse in many Nirṇaya and Paddhati granthas, from [Nirṇayasindhu of Kamalākara Bhaṭṭa](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.345177/page/n273/mode/1up) to Vaiṣṇava treatise like Chalārī Śeṣācārya's Nirṇayaratnam. Most of these either quote Kālikāpurāṇa or 'Devīpurāṇa' as the source. A variation of the verse can still be traced to [Kālikāpurāṇa's chapter dedicated to Viṣṇupūjanavidhi (88.15)](https://archive.org/details/KalikaPuranamVol.2AcharyaMrityunjayaTripathi/page/n611/mode/1up?view=theater). Interestingly, it states the verse to be that of यजुष.

> अस्यै प्राणाः प्रतिष्ठन्तु अस्यै प्राणाः क्षरन्तु यत्।
> अस्यै देवत्व संख्यायै स्वाहेति यजुरुच्चरन्।।

> asyai prāṇāḥ pratiṣṭhantu asyai prāṇāḥ kṣarantu ca।
> asyai devatva saṃkhyāyai svāheti yajuruccaran।।

> While reciting yajurmantra he should say this: let the spirit pervade this icon, let the spirit stay within it, let svāha bestow divinity on it. *- [Kalika Purana](https://archive.org/details/QCML_the-kalika-puran-translated-in-english-by-b-n-shastri-edited-by-surendra-pratap-nag-publishers-/page/n45/mode/2up) 88.15*

P.V. Kane in his ['History of Dharmaśāstra'](https://archive.org/details/kANe_history_of_dharmashAstra-s/v2p2/page/900/mode/1up) states the verse as quoted in Devapratiṣṭhātattva, Nirṇayasindhu, Rājadharmakaustubha among many others is based on Śāradātilaka Tantra's chapter dedicated to Prāṇapratiṣṭha. One can also find the verse in the aforementioned [Lakṣmīnārāyaṇa Saṃhitā](https://archive.org/details/lakShmInArAyaNasaMhitA2/page/n496/mode/1up), though not sequential to the first half.

If we look for both verses in **sequential** order, we can find them in Paddhati and Upāsanā texts or compilations. Gita Press' [Nityakarma Pūjāprakāśa by Lālabihārī Miśra](https://archive.org/details/zubk_nitya-karma-puja-prakash-by-lalvihari-mishra-gita-press/page/n196/mode/1up) and [Jīvana sudhā of Rāmajīlāla Śāstrī](https://archive.org/details/THdC_jivana-sudha-edited-by-rajaji-lal-shastri-published-by-ramji-lal-shastri-1990-be/page/%E0%A5%AD%E0%A5%AC/mode/1up) are example of this. With another verse, it can be found in [Yajñadīpikā as compiled by Dīpacanda Śāstrī](https://archive.org/details/xvDF_yagya-dipika-with-hindi-commentary-by-pt-dipachand-shastry-sri-kashi-vishvanath-samsthan-varana/page/n46/mode/1up?view=theater). You can also find it in multiple other Pūjā-vidhāna Rahasya(s).

Comment: Brilliant! I found the verses in Yajurveda 2.13 and Kalika Purana 88.15

Comment: Thank you! Do note that the one of Kālikāpurāṇa varies a bit and as I edited, the Purāṇa interestingly mentions even the second half to be that of यजुष - maybe from different recessions or in a non-sequential order which I unfortunately am not able to trace.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that the Purana itself says to use the Yajurveda mantra. The mantra I wrote in the question has some spelling mistakes. The Kalika Purana verse and the Yajurveda mantra are the right ones.

Comment: Interesting answer....